# TensorFlow Training CNN on Custom Images

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist, tensor

All the tensorflow tutorials do a great job, however, they all use preprocessed downloadable datasets that work out of the box.  Their tutorial on MNIST is the perfect example.
For a school project, 4 others and I have been assigned to train a CNN on supplied data in the form of PNG images. It's just a directory with 150 images.  The labels are contained in the image file names.

The way the codes sits now we are getting an error which I will include below.

We followed the MNIST code found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py

So we are fairly certain our problem is in how we have processed the image data.
We have been trying to get this to work for roughly 3 days.  (Many errors that we have worked through, this is just the latest).

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated!
Also, if anybody has questions about this please comment.

```
import os

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
#from PIL import Image


# a function
def cnn_model_fn(features,labels,mode):
    """Model function for CNN."""
    # Input Layer
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features['x'], [-1, 128, 128, 3])

    # Convolutional Layer #1
    conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[7, 7],
        strides=2,
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    conv_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=conv_1,
        filters=128,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        strides = 2,
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    max_pool_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
        inputs = conv_2,
        pool_size = 3,
        strides = 1
    )
    conv_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=max_pool_1,
        filters=96,
        kernel_size=[3, 3],
        activation=tf.nn.relu
    )
    max_pool_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
        inputs = conv_3,
        pool_size = 2,
        strides = 1
    )
    dropout_1 = tf.layers.dropout(
        inputs = max_pool_2,
        rate=0.5
    )
    fully_connected_1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        inputs = dropout_1,
        num_outputs = 1024,

    )
    dropout_2 = tf.layers.dropout(
        inputs = fully_connected_1,
        rate=0.5
    )
    fully_connected_2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        inputs = dropout_2,
        num_outputs = 1024,

    )
    fully_connected_3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        inputs = fully_connected_2,
        num_outputs = 15,

    )
    softmax_layer = tf.contrib.layers.softmax(
        logits = fully_connected_3
    )
#------------------------------------------------------------------------MAIN--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def getLabels():

    imagelabels_arr = []

    image_files = os.listdir("../assets/CNN-Data/")

    for image in image_files:
        imagelabels_arr.append(image.split('.')[len(image.split('.'))-2])

    return imagelabels_arr


def getTrainImages():

    filenames = []

    image_files = os.listdir("../assets/CNN-Data/")

    for image in image_files:
        filenames.append(image)

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(content, channels=3)
    images = np.asarray(image)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float64)
    resize_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, (128, 128))

   # image_batch = tf.train.batch([resize_image], batch_size=10)

    print(resize_image)
    return resize_image


with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="./test")

    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
          x={'x':np.array(getTrainImages())},
          y=np.array(getLabels()),
          batch_size=10,
          num_epochs=None,
          shuffle=True)

    classifier.train(
          input_fn=train_input_fn,
          steps=20,
          )
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN.py", line 134, in <module>
    steps=20,
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\tensorFlowPratice\flowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 241, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\tensorFlowPratice\flowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 628, in _train_model
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\tensorFlowPratice\flowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 499, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\tensorFlowPratice\flowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 585, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\tensorFlowPratice\flowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\numpy_io.py", line 109, in input_fn
    if len(set(v.shape[0] for v in ordered_dict_x.values())) != 1:
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\tensorFlowPratice\flowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\numpy_io.py", line 109, in <genexpr>
    if len(set(v.shape[0] for v in ordered_dict_x.values())) != 1:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: I don't know much about the `Estimator` API, but shouldn't `cnn_model_fn` return something?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  If we add the return statement the MNIST code is using we get the same error.

Comment: What does the statement `print(resize_image)` show? (or is it not running to that point?) Also side notes: 1) it doesn't affect the program, but `images = np.asarray(image)` does not make sense... `image` is a TF tensor, not NumPy 2) maybe what you want is `image = tf.cast(image / 255.0, tf.float64)` ? (to have pixel values in [0, 1])

Comment: It prints "Tensor("Squeeze:0", shape=(128, 128, 3), dtype=float32)" If I comment out the images = np.asarray(image) it prints the same thing.

Comment: If I use tf.cast(image/ 255.0, tf/float64) I get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Tensor' and 'float'

Comment: Right, sorry, it should be `tf.cast(image, tf.float64) / 255.0` in any case...

Comment: The problem is that you are using [`numpy_input_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn), which is for NumPy inputs, but `getTrainImages` returns a TensorFlow tensor object... wrapping it with `np.array` will only make it a NumPy "object" scalar (with no dimensions, hence the error about `v.shape`).

Answer (score 0):

`classifier.train` function expects numpy arrays, but not tensors. Hence you need to convert `example_batch, label batch` by evaluating them with a session, but not wrapping them using `np.array()` function. ([Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773873/tensorflow-training-cnn-on-custom-images#comment80519748_46773873))

```
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="./test")

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={'x':getTrainImages().eval()},
      y=getLabels().eval(),
      batch_size=10,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)

classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=20,
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommended to apply tools on top of tensorflow. You might consider to code it through roNNie, Theano, Keras, Torch or Caffe.