# tf.estimator.Estimator error message IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: image, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am new to Tensorflow and Python. I am attempting to train a deep network to use as a simple object detector with Tensorflow using my own images, primarily following the tutorials provided on Tensorflow.org. My operating system is Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6, and I am using Python 3.6 through Anaconda 3. I have written my images to training and validation tf.records files, and am reading and batching them in using the following file reader and input pipeline:

```
def read_file(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    key, record_string = reader.read(filename_queue)
    feature = {'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
           'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
    features = tf.parse_single_example(record_string, feature)
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.float32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [224, 224, 1])
    image.set_shape([224, 224, 1])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1 / 255.0)
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.float32)
    label = tf.reshape(label, [1,])
    return image, label


def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, read_threads, num_epochs):
    print ('input pipeline ready')
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(  
        [filenames], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)  
    image, label = [read_file(filename_queue)
    for _ in range(read_threads)]
    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch_join([image, label], 
        batch_size=batch_size, 
    capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    print('loading batch')
    return example_batch, label_batch
```

I have verified that this reads and batches my input files and labels correctly. I then define a convolutional neural network following the "Building a Convolutional Neural Network" tutorial (altering it for my grayscale images as needed), which I named cnn_model_fn. The training and loss functions are defined in cnn_model_fn as is seen in the tutorial.

I am attempting to perform training and validation using a tf.estimator.Estimator object, loading the batches into the estimator using an input function, code below:

```
def main(unused_argv):
# training images and labels
  example_batch, label_batch = input_pipeline(train_path, batch_size, 
    read_threads, num_epochs)
#validation images and labels
  Vexample_batch, Vlabel_batch = input_pipeline(val_path, batch_size, 
    read_threads, num_epochs)
  classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = cnn_model_fn, 
    model_dir=model_dir)
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, 
    every_n_iter=batch_size)
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
          x={"images": np.array(example_batch)},
          y=np.array(label_batch),
          batch_size= batch_size,
          num_epochs=num_epochs,
          shuffle=True)

  classifier.train(
      input_fn = train_input_fn,
      steps=int(label_batch.shape[0])/batch_size * num_epochs, hooks=
           [logging_hook])

  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": np.array(Vexample_batch)},
      y=np.array(Vlabel_batch),
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
  metrics = {
      "accuracy":
          learn.MetricSpec(
                  metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes")},

  eval_results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, metrics = 
       metrics)
  print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     tf.app.run()
```

The "classifier.train" command causes the following error message: "IndexError: tuple index out of range." I have also tried this not converting the image and label batches to np.arrays, and I get this error message: TypeError: unhashable type: 'Dimension' Full traceback to the first error message is provided at the end of the question. I have also tried using tf.contrib.learn.estimator.fit, both with the above input function and feeding the batches in directly, and am encountering similar problems with that approach. I cannot find any further information on this specific issue, and the Tensorflow.org tutorials are not shedding any more light onto this problem. I feel like I'm probably missing something pretty simple, but I'm at my wit's end trying to solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's the full traceback:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-ee71d4ff521a>", line 168, in <module>
    tf.app.run()

   File "/Users/BAMF/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
   packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

  File "<ipython-input-1-ee71d4ff521a>", line 151, in main
    steps=int(label_batch.shape[0])/batch_size * num_epochs, hooks=
[logging_hook])

  File "/Users/BAMF/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 241, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)

  File "/Users/BAMF/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 628, in _train_model
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  File "/Users/BAMF/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 499, in 
_get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)

  File "/Users/BAMF/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
 packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 585, in 
   _call_input_fn
     return input_fn(**kwargs)

 File "/Users/BAMF/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
 packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py", line 109, in i 
   nput_fn
        if len(set(v.shape[0] for v in ordered_dict_x.values())) != 1:

  File "/Users/BAMF/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py", line 109, in 
<genexpr>
    if len(set(v.shape[0] for v in ordered_dict_x.values())) != 1:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

`classifier.train` function expects numpy arrays, but not tensors. Hence you need to convert `example_batch, label batch` by evaluating them with a session, but not wrapping them using `np.array()` function. ([Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773873/tensorflow-training-cnn-on-custom-images#comment80519748_46773873))

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)


train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
          x={"images": example_batch.eval()},
          y=label_batch.eval(),
          batch_size= batch_size,
          num_epochs=num_epochs,
          shuffle=True)

  classifier.train(
      input_fn = train_input_fn,
      steps=int(label_batch.shape[0])/batch_size * num_epochs, hooks=
           [logging_hook])

  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x":Vexample_batch.eval()},
      y=Vlabel_batch.eval(),
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I incorporated these changes, with the addition of initializing all variables in a session, using tf.global_variables_initializer() with tf.local_variables_initializer(). This got the classifier.train() step to run but now I'm encountering a problem in evaluation. I get the error message "ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2 for 'remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,2]." I've tried reducing the dimensionality of the labels to a vector, no help. Any ideas what is causing that? Can give full stack and code if needed.

Comment: I'm also confused about something; isn't the purpose of grouping all of the training and evaluation procedures into a "main" function and calling it using "if __name__ == "__main__":" to initialize all variables at once and coordinate/stop the threads in a compact way? From the examples I'm following, it looks like this is the intended method when using the tf.estimator.modekeys (which I didn't show, but I am). Why do I need to call a session if calling my main function does that? Should I run a session in my main function? That seems redundant. Any clarification would be helpful. Thank you.